# Event listener for dynamically created html

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am dynamically generating html, and I want the elements I add to have event listeners.  The "board" div is in my html file, and I create the "myDiv" element.  This part works.

```
var board = document.getElementById("board");
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.innerHTML="this is my div";
```

Then I try to add an event listener to the "myDiv" div.  I have tried all of the following:

```
myDiv.onclick=function(){alert('click')};

myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('click')});

myDiv.onclick=myFunction //myFunction just creates an alert like the others
```

Then I append the 'myDiv' element to the board.  It shows up on the screen as expected

```
board.appendChild(myDiv);
```

The div elements show up as expected, and when I open the JavaScript console in Chrome it looks like that part is correct.  Also, the JavaScript console says that there is a 'click' event listener attached to the 'myDiv' div, but no alert ever comes up like it should.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Append the element before adding the listener

Comment: What you have works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/udjz9218/**

Comment: Can it be you have disabled alerts?

Comment: @caeth Disabling popups doesn't disable `alert()`.

Comment: Oh wait ! Actually if your browser receives too many alerts, an option pops up to disable future alerts (case for Firefox). Maybe it's because of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment about alerts disabled.

Under Firefox : type `about:config` in your adress bar and try switching

```
prompts.tab_modal.enabled
```

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/810240)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easy with using JQuery:

For example, your html:

```
<div id="Box"></div>
```

And you append data into div#Box, e.g.:

```
$('#Box').append('<div class="js-item">Some content</div>');
```

After that you have smth like:

```
<div id="Box"><div class="js-item">Some content</div></div>
```

You have to create listener in the following way:

```
$('#Box').on('click', '.js-item', function() { ... });
```

And it will work all elements that you will create.